# how to jump from editor to explorer window in eclipse(shortcut key)

Tags: eclipse

is there any shortcut key to jump from writing editor to explorer window or console ?
see the photo suppose I am writing code and I want to move project explorer window with out mouse use.so is there any shortcut key for that ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I got the answer
ctrl + shift + f7  or ctl+f7

Answer (score 0):

To find all the shortcuts in Eclipse; `Window - preferences: General - keys`

Then you might want to look into the plugin [Mousefeed](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/mousefeed), it will tell you if the action you performed with the mouse has a keyboard shortcuts. It will not help with switching views thought